# How to compress floating point data?

Tags: java, c, floating-point, compression

I have read the research on SPDP: An Automatically Synthesized Lossless Compression Algorithm for Floating-Point Data https://userweb.cs.txstate.edu/~mb92/papers/dcc18.pdf

Now I would like to implement a program to simulate the compression of floating point data. 
I do not know where to start. I have a text file with a set of real numbers inside.
I know that I have to use a mixing technique.
Better to use c or java?

I had thought about doing the XOR between the current value and the previous value. Then I count the frequency of these differences and finally I apply the Huffman algorithm.
Could it be right?

Any ideas to suggest?

Comment: So what's the algorithm?  Sorry, I don't think anyone's going to pay money to read that paper, just so they can answer your question.

Comment: Not only that - "where to start" is not a real question. Start with writing some code.

Comment: (a) Unfortunately, Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site. “I do not know where to start” is not an appropriate context for a question. (b) You say you know you have to use a “mixing technique,” but this is not in the paper you cite. We do not know what leads you to think this. (c) You say you thought about using XOR, but the paper does not indicate XOR was useful. It mentions XOR, but it seems the result of their synthesization used only arithmetic subtraction, not XOR. We do not know why you think XOR might be useful. It might be for the data you would be working with, but we do not know.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: “Start with writing some code” is not good advice for all situations, particularly one where the knowledge and experience required is somewhat above novice level.

Comment: @EricPostpischil From the question is *really* not clear what the OP is struggling with. Is it with reading the input file? Then it is a novice level knowledge. Is it with implementing the algorithm? Or with a choice of the language at all? These questions can be answered if *some* code is already written.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I know that the paper does not mention the XOR. They have examined existing compression algorithms and created components. The problem is that I would have 2 months to realize this thing. It takes a lot of time to analyze all the existing algorithms.
That's why I asked for ideas ....

Comment: @EugeneSh.: For none of those situations is “Start with writing some code” good advice. If a person does not know how to read an input file, they certainly are not prepared to implement floating-point data compression and need to study more about software in general. If a person does not know how to implement the algorithm, that is something that needs to be thought about conceptually first, and an implementation ought to be designed, not constructed by writing code. If a person does not know what language to use, then, again, they need to learn more, not start writing code.

Comment: I can read a file. I just wanted a clarification on how to move.

Answer (score 1):

According to the paper their code was compiled with `gcc/g++ 5.3.1 using the “-O3 -march=native” flags` so you can probably go with something like that. Also, this sounds like a short-run tool that would probably be better for `C` rather than `Java` anyway.

As for writing the algorithm, you will probably want to use the one they determined is best. In that case you'll need to read *slowly and carefully* what I have copied below. If there's anything you don't understand then you'll have to research further.

Carefully read the descriptions of each of the sub-algorithms (algorithmic components) and write their forward *and reversed* implementations - You need to write the reverse implementation so that you can decompress your data later.

Once you have all the sub-algorithms complete and tested, you can combine them as described into the synthesized algorithm. And also write the reversal for the synthesized algorithm.

The algorithmic components are described further farther below.

### 5.1. Synthesized Algorithm

> SPDP, the best-compressing four-component algorithm for our datasets in CRUSHER’s
>   9,400,320-entry search space is **LNVs2 | DIM8 LNVs1 LZa6**. Whereas there has to be a reducer component at the end, none appear in the first three positions, i.e., CRUSHER generated a three-stage data model followed by a one-stage coder. This result shows that chaining whole compression algorithms, each of which would include a reducer, is not beneficial. Also, the Cut appears after the first component, so it is important to first treat the data at word granularity and then at byte granularity to maximize the compression ratio.
>
> The **LNVs2** component at the beginning that operates at 4-byte granularity is of particular interest. It subtracts the second-previous value from the current value in the sequence and emits the residual. This enables the algorithm to handle both single- and double-precision data well. In case of 8-byte doubles, it takes the upper half of the previous double and subtracts it from the upper half of the current double. Then it does the same for the lower halves. The result is, except for a suppressed carry, the same as computing the difference sequence on 8-byte values. In case of 4-byte single-precision data, this component also computes the difference sequence, albeit using the second-to-last rather than the last value. If the values are similar, which is where difference sequences help, then the second-previous value is also similar and should yield residuals that cluster around zero as well. This observation answers our first research question. *We are able to learn from the synthesized algorithm, in this case how to handle mixed single/double-precision datasets*.
>
> The **DIM8** component after the **Cut** separates the bytes making up the single or double values such that the most significant bytes are grouped together, followed by the second most significant bytes, etc. This is likely done because the most significant bytes, which hold the exponent and top mantissa bits in IEEE 754 floating-point values, correlate more with each other than with the remaining bytes in the same value. This assumption is supported by the **LNVs1** component that follows, which computes the byte-granularity difference sequence and, therefore, exploits precisely this similarity between the bytes in the same position of consecutive values. The **LZa6** component compresses the resulting difference sequence. It uses *n* = 6 to avoid bad matches that result in zero counts being emitted, which expand rather than compress the data. The chosen high value of *n* indicates that bad matches are frequent, as is expected with relatively random datasets (cf. Table 1).

### 2.1. Algorithmic Components

> The **DIM*n*** component takes a parameter n that specifies the dimensionality and groups the values accordingly. For example, a dimension of three changes the linear sequence *x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3* into *x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3*. We use *n* = 2, 4, 8, and 12.

---

> The **LNV*kn*** component takes two parameters. It subtracts the last *n*th value from the current value and emits the residual. If k = ‘s’, arithmetic subtraction is used. If k = ‘x’, bitwise subtraction (xor) is used. In both cases, we tested n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 12, 16, 32, and 64. None of the above components change the size of the data blocks. The next three components are the only ones that can reduce the length of a data block, i.e., compress it.

---

> The **LZ*ln*** component implements a variant of the **LZ77** algorithm (Ziv, J. and A. Lempel. “A Universal Algorithm for Data Compression.” *IEEE Transaction
>   on Information Theory*, Vol. 23, No. 3, pp. 337-343. 1977). It incorporates tradeoffs that make it more efficient than other LZ77 versions on hard-to-compress data and operates as follows. It uses a 32768-entry hash table to identify the *l* most recent prior occurrences of the current value. Then it checks whether the *n* values immediately preceding those locations match the *n* values just before the current location. If they do not, only the current value is emitted and the component advances to the next value. If the *n* values match, the component counts how many values following the current value match the values after that location. The length of the matching substring is emitted and the component advances by that many values. We consider *n* = 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7 combined with *l* = ‘a’, ‘b’, and ‘c’, where ‘a’ = 1, ‘b’ = 2, and ‘c’ = 4, which yields fifteen LZ*ln* components.

---

> The **│** pseudo component, called the **Cut** and denoted by a vertical bar, is a singleton component that converts a sequence of words into a sequence of bytes. Every algorithm produced by CRUSHER contains a Cut, which is included because it may be more effective to perform none, some, or all of the compression at byte rather than word granularity.

Remember that you'll need to also include the reversal of these algorithms if you want to decompress your data.

I hope this clarification helped, and best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The SPDP algorithm is already available.
I should write the other components. I will read more calmly.

Comment: Yea, a few of the algorithmic components may be available. It could just come down to combining them into the synthesized algorithm.

Comment: Are the components already made available on the web? I can not find anything. I have little time to implement this algorithm. For now, I have LNVs2 | DIM8 LNVs1 LZa6.

Comment: If you say "the SPDP algorithm is already available" then you've answered your own question. If you have it then use it. Otherwise I have no more knowledge than you on where you might find pre-existing implementations of these algorithms.

Comment: I had assumed this was something you wanted or needed to implement for yourself, but if you just need the algorithm, and you have the algorithm, then what is the question?

Comment: I should write the other components for simulate crusher framework for synthesized algorithm...

Answer (score 0):

Burtscher has several papers on floating point compression. Before jumping in to SPDP you might want to try this paper https://userweb.cs.txstate.edu/~burtscher/papers/tr08.pdf.  The paper has a code listing on page 7; you might just copy and paste it in to a C file which you can experiment with before attempting harder algorithms.

Secondly, do not expect these FP compression algorithms to compress all floating point data. To get a good compression ratio neighboring FP values are expected to be numerically close to each other or exhibit some pattern that repeats itself. Burtscher uses a method called Finite Context Modeling (FCM) and differential FCM: "I have seen this pattern before; let me predict the next value and then XOR the actual and predicted values to achieve compression..."